# Exam Probability

Tags: probability

A student has discovered that the probability of failing any exam is $p = .8$ if she studies less than 2 hours. Suppose she has three exams one day and studies only one hour for each. What is the probability that she fails two or more exams?

I have the feeling that I need to use the Binomial Distribution with $P (X \geq 2) = 1 - P(X = 0) - P(X = 1)$, using $n = 3$ for each, $k = 0, 1$ respectively for the two probabilities, and $p = 0.8$. Is this on the right track?

Comment: Interesting -- I don't really understand the problem. From the setup, it's not clear that studying for one hour is any more helpful than studying not at all. So it's just a problem in finite probability.

Comment: In that case, the probability that she fails 3 is (.8)^3 and the probability that she fails 2 is 3*(.8)^2*(.2), so just add those up.

Comment: Of course, this assuming that the events are independent.  That may or may not be true, but the question should specify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the events are independent (which I would assume because they are exams on the same day) you and hunter were on the right track. There are four total events that can happen, but 8 different outcomes:

```
0. She can pass all the exams(there is one way this can happen)
1. She can fail one exam and pass two (there are 3 ways this can happen)
2. She can fail two exams and pass one (there are 3 ways this can happen)  
3. She can fail all 3 (there is one way this can happen)
```

There are two ways to solve this problem.

You can add the probability of event 0 and 1 together and subtract the sum from 1:

```
P(e) = 1 - (P(0) + P(1))
P(0) = 0.2 * 0.2 * 0.2 * 1
P(1) = 0.2 * 0.2 * 0.8 * 3
P(e) = 1 - ((0.008) + (0.096))
P(e) = 0.896
```

Or you can add the probability of event 2 and 3 together:

```
P(e) = P(2) + P(3)
P(2) = 0.8 * 0.8 * 0.2 * 3
P(3) = 0.8 * 0.8 * 0.8 * 1
P(e) = (0.384) + (0.512)
P(e) = 0.896
```

They are the same and required almost the same amount of work. And just to double check if you add P(0), P(1), P(2), and P(3) together you get 1.

```
P(t) = (0.008) + (0.096) + (0.384) + (0.512) = 1
```

The big key here is knowing that even there are a total of 4 events happening, there are 8 different possibilities.